# MySQL How to use and OR inside an AND operator for a where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, or-operator, and-operator

I'm trying to use AND with OR's inside my WHERE clause but I'm not getting expected results. This is my query:

```
select * 
  from Pitches 
 where BatterID = @playerID 
   and YEAR(GameDate) in (2019) 
   and (BattedBallID is not null or BattedBallID <> 0);
```

The problem is I'm getting BattedBallID's that have 0 in the rows but none of them have null. I want it so my results have BattedBallID's that aren't 0 and aren't null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want it so my results have BattedBallID's that aren't 0 and aren't null;

You want:

```
and BattedBallID is not null and BattedBallID <> 0;
```

Instead of:

```
and (BattedBallID is not null or BattedBallID <> 0);
```

Your original expression will actually always evaluate as true, since both conditions cannot be false at the same time : if something is `null`, then it is not equal to `0`, and if something is equal to `0`, then it is not `null`.